# How to interlink firebase storage file with firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security, firebase-storage

I want to make a table of person containing it's image. Like :

```
{
"person" : 
    {
        name : "xyz",
        image : "path_of_firebase_storage"
    }
}
```

**Que1 : Is it possible to upload the person value with image at one time?**

**Que2 : When I delete the person, then associated image in the firebase storage should also get deleted. Is is possible to do this?**

*So my requirement is, I want to do CURD operation on image via CURD operation of person.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found your question facing the same problem. Probably You already solved it, but I will answer it anyway for other searchers.

> **Que1 : Is it possible to upload the person value with image at one time?**

No, it's not possible. In my implementation at the beginning I upload photo into Firebase Storage and save the file information (timestamp + file name). After that I upload my object* with included filename value to Firebase Database. Each user has his own directory, so that's enough.

> **Que2 : When I delete the person, then associated image in the firebase storage should also get deleted. Is is possible to do this?**

No, you have to delete it manually as you would when uploading it. You separately remove the object* and the photo.

**But,**

I didn't check how Firebase Functions work. Probably You can write function and delete all photos without owner. You could run this function once a day/week.

*object - I serialize entire object into JSON ;)